# How to slide html pages automatically using Sencha Touch and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch

I am creating simple app using Sencha Touch, JavaScript and HTML 5 
in that app I want to slide html pages automatically in how to do it ?

I use following code to show html pages with images.

`main.js` file:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Carousel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    config: {
        ui : 'light'
    },

    items: [
        {
            html : '<img src="resources/images/Picture1.png" width="100%" height = "100%" align="middle" /> <audio autoplay loop><source src="resources/audio/music1.mp3"></audio>',
            style: 'backgroundImage: url(resources/images/bg.png);backgroundRepeat: repeat;backgroundPosition: center'
        },
        {
            html : '<img src="resources/images/Picture2.png" width="100%" height = "100%" margin=0 align="middle" />',
            style: 'backgroundImage: url(resources/images/bg.png);backgroundRepeat: repeat;backgroundPosition: center'
        },
        {
            html : '<img src="resources/images/Picture3.png" width="100%" height = "100%" margin=0 align="middle" />',
            style: 'backgroundImage: url(resources/images/bg.png);backgroundRepeat: repeat;backgroundPosition: center'
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: do you mean to create something like a slideshow through html pages?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Ext JS [Task Runner](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner). In the function you need to write logic for moving through different items. You probably might have to put the items in panel and then slide the panels across the screen.

Comment: Have you followed the link provided in the response. it takes you to Sencha Docs page.

Comment: sorry but Sencha Touch and Ext JS (especially Ext 3.x) are totally different products

Comment: Sencha is built on top of Ext JS Only, so they are not completely different products. Every thing which is defined in extJS, you can use that stuff in Sencha App also.

Comment: I know that but here I just want to emphasize that they are not the same, both classes and behind-the-scene work principles. At the link you should try another product's docs, such as Sencha Touch 1 or Sencha Touch 2 docs and that util is no longer available